# Canonical Links - Same file on server

Tags: seo, canonical-link

I am using Microsoft's IIS SEO analyzer, and it keeps showing me a warning that I have a canonical link error because I'm storing the same file in different folders on the server.  Doing this makes my file structure much more organized that linking different folders together.  Should I just ignore this or is this a big deal for SEO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where files are located on your server has nothing to do with SEO. There is no way for search engines to know where files are actually located and a page's URL dos not necessarily indicate its location on the server. What does matter is whether two URLs pull up the same page. That would be duplicate content and a problem for your SEO efforts.